# How to set an error message with Javascript?

Tags: status-messages, javascript

I was wondering how to set an error message from js to Drupal ?
something like

```
<?php
    drupal_set_message('mplampla);
?>
```

but in Drupal object in js

```
jQuery(document).ready (function(){
    Drupal.setErrorMessage('mplampla');
})
```

is this even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `drupal_set_message()` works by storing the messages into a session and displays when the page is reloaded.

If you want to show an error message through javascript, include js in your module (if working with some module).

You could simply append an error message on some event

```
    jQuery(document).ready (function(){
    jQuery(".error-message").append('<div class="messages error">Error message to be displayed</div>');
});
```

It will simply display an error message. You can apply further Js code as desired output.

Comment: yes that would suffice thank you :D
actually i would like to go a bit further and have a ready function to set a message so i could use jquery and build a function that will delete and /or show a message ;)

Comment: However in this case you hardcode the wrapper:
What is the general error message div wrapper changes? You have to edit it at each places.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach the message above the form you can do

```
jQuery("form").prepend('<div class="messages error">Error message to be displayed</div>');
```

Based on Adrian Cid Almaguer answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 and later you can use core/drupal.message library for that.

Add the core/drupal.message as a dependency for your custom library.

To add a message using Drupal messages API you need:

```
const message = new Drupal.Message();
message.add('Please enter your name', {type: 'error'});
message.add('Something happen', {type: 'warning'});
```

To clear the messages use the `message.clear();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jQuery Validate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/). it populates the HTML errors containers with proper messages.

regards

Sudheesh